# streamlit date input to filter Series dataframe

Tags: python, streamlit

I have been getting this error **TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'datetime.date'**

I have a series data frame that contains some values where the date is the index. The date is already formatted in '%Y-%m-%d'.

I am using streamlit data input to filter my data, but it is not working :(

The date format below, I was hoping the user input would be consistent with my current date format.

```py
start_date = st.date_input('Start Date', value = pd.to_datetime('2021-01-31', format='%Y-%m-%d'))
end = st.date_input('End Date', value = pd.to_datetime('today', format='%Y-%m-%d'))

st.table(Series.loc[start_date:end])
```

Answer (score 2):

The output of `st.date_input` is always a `datetime.date` object. When you give it to `.loc`, it tries to compare dates in string format and dates in `datetime.date` format. In order to do what you want to do, you just need to convert your dates to string before feeding them to `.loc`:

```py
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd

start_date = st.date_input("Start Date", value=pd.to_datetime("2021-01-31", format="%Y-%m-%d"))
end_date = st.date_input("End Date", value=pd.to_datetime("today", format="%Y-%m-%d"))

# convert the dates to string
start = start_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
end = end_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

st.table(Series.loc[start:end])
```